# LED still glowing with a capacitor in series

Tags: led, capacitor, series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm4i8Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a 470ohm resistor, 22uF capacitor and a 5mm LED in series (same sequence as described), connected to a 9V DC battery. I was expecting the LED to fade away but it didn't, it continues to glow with full power.

I am not able to understand why, your inputs will provide clarity.

Edit:

I realized that the polarity of capacitor was reversed. I corrected it and am now getting the expected result. However, I'm still confused as to why the LED was lit when the capacitor was reversed.

Comment: If the capacitor is polarised have you got it the correct way round?

Comment: There is a schematic diagram editor you can use if you click "edit" under your question.  Draw your circuit with it.  Diagrams make it easier to discuss circuits.

Comment: Bang on Steve. But confused why did the wrong polarity continue to lit the LED

Comment: @trickyal: because leakage current is a thing

Comment: Because a reverse bias electrolytic capacitor doesn't work as a capacitor - it becomes two metal plates in an electrolyte.

Comment: http://www.crazyengineers.com/threads/connecting-polarised-capacitor-with-wrong-polarity-what-happens.59400/ *quote* "The dielectric in such capacitors is an integral oxide film produced by anodizing the anode (aluminium or tantalum foil) at a voltage about 10% higher than the rated voltage of the capacitor. This oxide film is insulating. To ensure that the film is intact and self repairing, an electrolyte is kept in an absorbent medium between the anode and cathode.
The film is destroyed if the voltage is reversed and only a bare metal results." - and what does bare metals make?

Comment: Thanks all. Now planning to close the thread. If someone could suggest how to close it.

Comment: Don't close it.  Let someone answer it, then accept the answer.  This is a good question that could help someone else.  All it needs is a good answer posted as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Also, since it turned out to be important, it would be good if your diagram showed a polarized capacitor connected backwards.  If this case, that would be with the positive (straight) side connected to the LED.

Comment: @SteveG, you should take this one and answer it!

Comment: @JRE not able to find the polarized capacitor symbol in the workbench nor a +ve or -ve symbol. Suggestions plz

Comment: @JRE thanks for the edit. where did you get the symbols?

Comment: You have to double click on the capacitor, then you can change it's type. Or right click, edit.

Comment: I had to look for it myself.  You right click the capacitor.  Open the properties.  Polarized is a property that you can select.  Then you can rotate the part.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Electrolytic cap leakage current is typically single digit µA. That's far from the 10-20mA that are needed to light up that 5mm LED.

Comment: @DerManu: LEDs start to light up at µA levels and are perceived to be "fully on" often far befor even 1mA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The electrolytic cap in your circuit is reverse biased. The reverse biasing of the capacitor removes the isolating oxide layer, so it allows current to pass. If you connect the capacitor the right way after mistreating it this way, the electrochemical process that dissolved the oxide layer is reversed and the capacitor recovers. You have to be careful to limit the current through the capacitor, because high currents caused by leaks in the oxide layer can permanently damage the capacitor. The dropper resistor in your LED circuit is likely enough to limit the current to safe values, but do not connect an electrolytic capacitor that got reversed directly to a battery or lab supply without setting a current limit.

The isolating oxide layer can not only be damaged by reverse polarity, but also dissolve over time if no voltage is applied to the cap. As soon as forward voltage is applied, the leakage current cures the oxide layer by electrolysis, so the cap heals itself. This is why it is sometimes recommended to slowly ramp up the voltage on vintage tube radios that were unpowered for dozens of years, although in some configuration under-heating a tube is bad for the cathode. The process of creating or restoring the oxide layer is called *forming*.

So as you likely understood, you can abuse an electrolytic cap as rectifier, because it conducts current when reverse biased, but blocks current when polarized the correct way. People actually did use a similar configuration of electrodes and electrolyte as you find in an electrolytic cap as rectifiers before semiconductor rectifiers were invented. They were called electrolytic rectifiers.

Comment: I was under the impression--probably from watching too many YouTube videos--that if you connect an electrolytic capacitor backwards, it will explode. Is that only true for high voltages or currents? What is safe?

Comment: Capacitors can "explode" if the electrolyte gets gaseous. This could happen either caused by temperature (through resistive heating) or by electrolysis of the electrolyte (it contains water, so you can split it into oxygen and hydrogen). For thermal destruction, its just the current that is important, it might either be AC or DC. The amount of gas produced by electrolysis also depends on the current, but in this case it has to be DC. To get DC current through a capacitor, you have to destroy the isolating oxide either with reverse voltage or over voltage.

Comment: @Willis Electrolytic caps are not specified to operate conductively with reverse voltage applied, so there us no definitely safe current. A rule of thumb is that typical caps are not destroyed by applying line-frequency AC if it does not exceed around 3% of the rated DC voltage. I expect this rule to be false for high-capacitance low ESR caps, because even low voltages mean a lot of charge.